# An issue when rendering a line depending on Mouse position

Tags: c++, qt, mouseevent, mousemove, mouseclick-event

I have an openGL widget, where I want to render a line which is dependent of mouse positions, as follows:

```
        glPushMatrix();
        glEnable(GL_BLEND);
        glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
        glColor4f(1, 0, 0, 0.1);
        glScalef(a, b, 0);
        glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glVertex2f(pushedX, pushedY);
        glVertex2f(currentX, currentY);
        glEnd();
        glFlush();
        glDisable(GL_BLEND);
        glPopMatrix();
```

**where:**

```
pushedX=buttonPressCoordinates.x();
pushedY=buttonPressCoordinates.y();
currentX=mouseCurrentPosition.x();
currentY=mouseCurrentPosition.y();
```

The rendering goes good, and the line is rendered as required when I move the mouse connecting with line the pushed and current coordinates.

**BUT:**

the issue is, that even when I press my mouse somewhere on the widget and don't move it, it generates randomly (as I think) some (x,y) and connects the it with a line with the coordinates of mouse pressed position. Though when I start moving my mouse it starts working fine.

Please, help to fix this bug.

**EDIT**

*The code of assigning the current values of the mouse*

```
void MainWindow::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *eventMove)
{
    if(eventMove->buttons() & Qt::LeftButton)
    {
        GLWidget *widget = this->findChild<GLWidget *>("glwidget");
        float x = widget->getNormalizedWidth(widget->mapFromGlobal(QCursor::pos()).x());
        float y = widget->getNormalizedHeight(widget->mapFromGlobal(QCursor::pos()).y());
        float y_ = 1.0 - y;
        mouseCurrentPosition.setX(x);
        mouseCurrentPosition.setY(y_);
        widget->setCurrentX(mouseCurrentPosition.x());
        widget->setCurrentY(mouseCurrentPosition.y());
    }
}
```

**note:** `QPointF mouseCurrentPosition;`, `getNormalizedWidth(...)` is my defined fundction which works perfect.

**EDIT-2**

*The mouse click coordinates are updated as follows:*

```
setMouseTracking(true);
m = true;
GLWidget *widget = this->findChild<GLWidget *>("glwidget");
float x = widget->getNormalizedWidth(widget->mapFromGlobal(QCursor::pos()).x());
float y = widget->getNormalizedHeight(widget->mapFromGlobal(QCursor::pos()).y());
float y_ = 1.0 - y;
buttonPressCoordinates.setX(x);
buttonPressCoordinates.setY(y_);
qDebug() << buttonPressCoordinates.x() << buttonPressCoordinates.y();
widget->setQ(true);
widget->setPushedX(buttonPressCoordinates.x());
widget->setPushedY(buttonPressCoordinates.y());
```

Comment: How often do you update currentX and currentY?

Comment: @Paddyd whenever my mouse is moved over the widget.

Comment: @Paddyd "idled" - what you mean?

Comment: Does this happen only on the first click?

Comment: @Paddyd it happens after every click, BUT sometimes (random times) it doesn't happen. For example if I start clicking really fast, the bug may not appear for further 2 clicks, and then again appear.

Comment: @Paddyd sorry, I guess it was not your comment, just someone commented and deleted the comment, I thought it was written by you. Sorry.

Comment: It has to be something to do with your assigning values of currentX and currentY. Can you include that code aswell please?

Comment: @Paddyd Please see the post edited in a minute.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36733/discussion-between-mike-and-paddyd)

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can try is to update `currentX` and `currentY` in the `mouseMoveEvent` when `LeftButton` is not pressed:

```
void MainWindow::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *eventMove)
{

     GLWidget *widget = this->findChild<GLWidget *>("glwidget");
     float x = widget->getNormalizedWidth(widget->mapFromGlobal(QCursor::pos()).x());
     float y = widget->getNormalizedHeight(widget->mapFromGlobal(QCursor::pos()).y());
     float y_ = 1.0 - y;

    if(eventMove->buttons() & Qt::LeftButton)
    {      
        buttonPressCoordinates.setX(x);
        buttonPressCoordinates.setY(y_);      
        widget->setPushedX(buttonPressCoordinates.x());
        widget->setPushedY(buttonPressCoordinates.y());
    }
    else
    {
        mouseCurrentPosition.setX(x);
        mouseCurrentPosition.setY(y_);
        widget->setCurrentX(mouseCurrentPosition.x());
        widget->setCurrentY(mouseCurrentPosition.y());
    }
}
```

Comment: widget->setCurrentX(mouseCurrentPosition.x());
widget->setCurrentY(mouseCurrentPosition.y()); this is the update

Comment: Nop, still cannot catch the bug :(

Comment: That also didn't help. I made some test for understanding how the points are generated. I noticed that every n seconds mouse position is re-saved on widget. And the lines are render to that re-saved coordinates.